# Como hacer un .exe en linux y qt

Tags: c++, qt, compilador

ultimo error que obtengo al hacer make:
ya hice lo del mxe root y lo de el make pero al hacer el make me da esto

> make[1]: i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++: No se encontró el programa
>   Makefile.Release:333: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
>   'release/main.o' make[1]: *** [release/main.o] Error 127 make[1]: se
>   sale del directorio '/home/omar/Escritorio/Juntador/binder'
>   Makefile:34: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'release'
>   make: *** [release] Error 2

No se porque

> MXE Warning! Downloading freetds from backup.
>
> ### Download failed or wrong checksum of package freetds!
>
> --2016-12-17 00:25:37--  http://d1yihgixbnrglp.cloudfront.net/freetds%2D1%2E00%2E23%2Etar%2Ebz2
>   Resolviendo d1yihgixbnrglp.cloudfront.net
>   (d1yihgixbnrglp.cloudfront.net)... 54.230.216.115, 54.230.216.109,
>   54.230.216.205, ... Conectando con d1yihgixbnrglp.cloudfront.net (d1yihgixbnrglp.cloudfront.net)[54.230.216.115]:80... conectado.
>   Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 404 Not Found 2016-12-17
>   00:25:37 ERROR 404: Not Found. Download failed!
>   ------------------------------------------------------------ [log]      /home/omar/Escritorio/mxe/log/freetds-download
>
> Makefile:488: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
>   'download-only-freetds-1.00.23.tar.bz2' make: ***
>   [download-only-freetds-1.00.23.tar.bz2] Error 1

Me muestra el siguiente error cuando hago make qtbase:

> bash: autoconf: no se encontró la orden Wrong version of requirement:
>   autoconf bash: automake: no se encontró la orden Wrong version of
>   requirement: automake
>
> Please have a look at "docs/index.html" to ensure that your system
>   meets all requirements.
>
> Makefile:376: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
>   '/home/omar/Escritorio/mxe/usr/installed/check-requirements' make: ***
>   [/home/omar/Escritorio/mxe/usr/installed/check-requirements] Error 1

Quiero que cuando compile se me genere un fichero .exe compatible con windows ya que la compilación en linux no es compatible con windows. Para eso he estado buscando información sobre el cross-compiling la compilación en distintas plataformas y encontre como hacerlo desde el siguiente enlace de stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591

Pero sigo sin entender muy bien como hacerlo. Muchos de estos comandos donde los usare en linux (desde la terminal?) y en que ubicación lo siento pero estoy un poco perdido.
Cuando digo comandos me refiero:

```
cd mxe && make qtbase
```

Aqui que debería poner en que parte debo poner la ubicación de mi aplicación:

```
<mxe root>/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
```

Si alguien puede explicarme más o menos como podría compilar un .exe para linux de un modo comprensible o decirme exactamente que hacer con cada cosa ya que no sé como llevarla a cabo todavía.

Comment: Qué no entiendes exactamente??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Descarga la aplicación mediante el siguiente comando, lo descargará en una carpeta llamada `mxe`:

   git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git
2. Despues debes instalar las dependecias, en este [link](http://mxe.cc/#requirements) estan, hay algunas recomendaciones para las distribuciones más conocidad, sino tendrás que buscar el nombre del paquete en tu distribución.
3. Debes ingresar a la carpeta `mxe` y compilar el archivo con la ayuda de su makefile, todo esto se hace con el siguiente comando(qtbase es el paquete base, si deseas otros paquetes escribelos a su costado, en el link anterior hay una parte donde dice `List of Packages` donde se encuentran los nombres de otros paquetes):

   cd mxe && make qtbase
4. Ahora abre una terminal en la carpeta de tu proyecto, verifica que solo se encuentren los archivos fuente, no archivos intermedios como `.pro.user`, `.o` u otros que hallas generado al compilarlo en linux y luego ejecuta el siguiente comando(donde `{mxe root}` es la ruta de la carpeta donde descargaste `mxe`), esta acción generara un makefile pero para windows:

   {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5
5. Despues ejecuta `make` para compilar.

Observaciones: si te sale un error por que no te encuentra algun archivo podrias linkear ese archivo que debe encontrarse en la carpeta mxe a la carpeta `/usr/bin`:

```
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ar /usr/bin
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 /usr/bin
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++  /usr/bin  
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-windres /usr/bin
ln -s {mxe root}/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-gcc /usr/bin
```

Además puedes utilizar wine para ejecutar tu ejecutable.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50213/discussion-between-eyllanesc-and-jeronimo-urtado).